# Python Requests Не получается перейти на сайт по прямой ссылке

Tags: python, html, requests

Я реализовал небольшой скрипт. Суть в том что он заходит на сайт дневник ру, авторизируется. Его перекидывает на главную страницу. Далее мне необходимо перейти по прямой ссылке на страницу с оценками, но это почему-то не получается. Ни руками в браузере, ни скриптом. При переходе на эту ссылку перебрасывает на главную страницу сайта. Однако если попытаться зайти туда с помощью кнопок, то все прекрасно получится. (Нажать дневник -> по семестрам, тогда на страницу с оценками перекинет, а по прямой ссылке не заходится) Как это обойти? Вот код:

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()

link = 'https://login.dnevnik.ru/login'

user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

r = session.get(link, headers={
    'User-Agent': user
})

session.headers.update({'Referer': link})

session.headers.update({'User-Agent': user})

_xsrf = session.cookies.get('_xsrf', domain=".dnevnik.ru")

response = session.post(link, {
    'login': 'тут логин',
    'password': 'тут пароль',
    '_xsrf': _xsrf,
    'remember': 'yes',
})

# На этом этапе создается ссылка на страницу с оценками, но при заходе на нее перекидывает на главную страницу сайта
journal = 'https://schools.dnevnik.ru/marks.aspx'
param = {'school': тут номер школы, 'index': 0, 'tab': 'period', 'homebasededucation': 'False'}
journal_response = session.get(journal, params=param).text

with open("123.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(journal_response)

print(journal_response)
```

Comment: А в `_xsrf` значение присутствует? Возможно, нужно какие-то заголовки в запрос добавить

Comment: В какой запрос?

Comment: Я открыл код элемента -> network и зашел на страницу с оценками.
Там в Headers есть строчка X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://dnevnik.ru
Может быть из-за этого не получается напрямую туда зайти, а только с главной страницы? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое обойти

Comment: Во все запросы. Посмотрите какие заголовки запроса (HTTP Header) заполняет браузер и повторите. Не все имеют смысл и обязательны, но это зависит от сервера. А про тот заголовок можно тут почитать: https://habr.com/ru/post/317720/, но это про iframe

Comment: Я добавил еще несколько заголовков в запрос и это сработало! Спасибо Вам огромное!!

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста сами ответ с решением, кнопка ниже ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
journal_response = session.get(journal, headers={
        '_xsrf': _xsrf,
        'remember': 'yes',
        '_ga': _ga,
        'DnevnikAuth_a': DnevnikAuth_a,
        '_gid': _gid,
        'dnevnik_sst': dnevnik_sst,
        '_ym_uid': _ym_uid,
        '_ym_d': _ym_d,
        'domain': '.dnevnik.ru',
        'Referer': 'https://schools.dnevnik.ru/marks.aspx?school=тут номер школы&tab=week'
    }, params=param).text
```